# How to compute (alt, az) for given Galactic coordinate (GLON, GLAT) with PyEphem?

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, astronomy, pyephem

For a given observer (lon, lat, time) on Earth and a given Galactic coordinate (GLON, GLAT), how can I compute the corresponding (alt, az) point in the sky with PyEphem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the way that PyEphem currently works, there are two steps to answering your question. First, you have to convert a pair of galactic coordinates into an equatorial RA/dec pair of coordinates instead.

```
import ephem

# Convert a Galactic coordinate to RA and dec                          

galactic_center = ephem.Galactic(0, 0)
eq = ephem.Equatorial(galactic_center)
print 'RA:', eq.ra, 'dec:', eq.dec

→ RA: 17:45:37.20 dec: -28:56:10.2
```

Those coordinates are pretty close to the ones that the Wikipedia gives for the galactic center.

Now that we have a normal RA/dec coordinate, we just need to figure out where it is in the sky right now. Since PyEphem is built atop a library that knows only about celestial “bodies” like stars and planets, we simply need to create a fake “star” at that location and ask its azimuth and altitude.

```
# So where is that RA and dec above Boston?
# Pretend that a star or other fixed body is there.

body = ephem.FixedBody()
body._ra = eq.ra
body._dec = eq.dec
body._epoch = eq.epoch

obs = ephem.city('Boston')
obs.date = '2012/6/24 02:00' # 10pm EDT
body.compute(obs)
print 'Az:', body.az, 'Alt:', body.alt

→ Az: 149:07:25.6 Alt: 11:48:43.0
```

And we can check that this answer is reasonable by looking at a sky chart for Boston late that evening: Sagittarius — the location of the Galactic Center — is just rising over the southeastern rim of the sky, which makes perfect sense of a southeast azimuth like 149°, and for an as-yet low altitude like 11°.

Comment: The (RA,DEC) coordinate from PyEphem matches exactly the one I find with the [HEASARC coordinate converter](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/Tools/convcoord/convcoord.pl), maybe the [Wikipedia/Galactic_Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center) position is for the black hole and not for (GLON,GLAT) = (0,0).

Comment: You could change `eq = ephem.Equatorial(galactic_center)` to `equatorial = ephem.Equatorial(galactic_center)`, then the code will run directly when pasted in a python shell.

Comment: This solution is very nice and simply. The only weird thing is that you assign private attributes of body instead of setting the values in the constructor.

Comment: I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6873013/498873) that it is possible to give coordinates "in the usual python way" to the constructor like this `body = ephem.FixedBody(ra=123.123, dec=45.45)`, but for some reason neiter `body = ephem.FixedBody(ra=eq.ra, dec=eq.dec)` nor `body = ephem.FixedBody(ra=eq.ra.real, dec=eq.dec.real)` works for me, in both cases I get `body._ra == 0`. Why is that?